# Getting Error( : 22091) >: argument 1 must be: number - GIMP Script-fu

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I have many images about 100 with me, and i need to resize all the images using the scaling factor. But, when i run the script, it shows me the following error

```
Error: ( : 22091) >: argument 1 must be: number
```

I am not an expert in Script-Fu, so I could not find any resources that can help me. Below is my script, and any help would be appreciated.

```
(define (batch-resize pattern scaleFactor)
(let* ((filelist (cadr (file-glob pattern 1))))
(while (not (null? filelist))
(let* ((filename (car filelist))
(image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE filename filename)))
(drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)))
(imageWidth) (gimp-image-width image)
(imageHeight) (gimp-image-height image))
(let * ((imageFactor 1))
(if (> imageWidth imageHeight) 
((set! imageFactor (/ imageWidth scaleFactor))) ((set! imageFactor (/ imageHeight scaleFactor))))
(set! imageWidth (/ imageWidth imageFactor))
(set! imageHeight (/ imageHeight imageFactor)))
(gimp-image-scale-full image imageWidth imageHeight INTERPOLATION-CUBIC)
(gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable filename filename)
(gimp-image-delete image))
(set! filelist (cdr filelist)))))
```

Comment: 1) doing that with Gimp is complete overkill, see command-line utilities such as ImageMagick instead, and 2) any hint at the instruction/API call that causes it?

Comment: Also, add a few gimp-message calls in you code to show some variables. A potential culprit could be "image" if the image didn't load correctly

Comment: @xenoid re: 1) You have no idea what OP's motivations are and really shouldn't discount their approach without any context. They could be undertaking this exercise in order to learn Scheme, the Gimp plugin API or for an almost endless number of other reasons.

Comment: My experience (and I have been helping people with Gimp and Gimp scripting for over 8 years), is that these questions usually come from people who have only considered Gimp and [don't know about the other tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) (the one exception was someone whose employer mandated Gimp...).

Answer (score 1):

You've got two issues, the first being you're not assigning `imageWidth` or `imageHeight`. Your brackets encapsulating the fetch image width/height calls go nowhere. So when the `(> imageWidth imageHeight)` is evaluated, imageWidth/imageHeight are not numbers.
`(imageWidth) (gimp-image-width image)` should be `(imageWidth (gimp-image-width image))` to assign the return value.

But the other problem is that, while the gimp documentation says it returns an INT32 (from what I could tell), most gimp api calls actually return a list, even if there is only one element in the list (See [tutorial/docs](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Scheme2/)). You need to call `car` on the result, which grabs the first element of the list, to use it in scheme.

Personal preference, but you might find it easier to see syntax/scoping issues with indenting.

```
(define (batch-resize pattern scaleFactor)
    (let* ((filelist (cadr (file-glob pattern 1))))
        (while (not (null? filelist))
            (let* (
                    (filename (car filelist))
                    (image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE filename filename)))
                    (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)))
                    (imageWidth (car (gimp-image-width image)))
                    (imageHeight (car (gimp-image-height image)))
                )
                (let * ((imageFactor 1))
                    (if (> imageWidth imageHeight) 
                        ((set! imageFactor (/ imageWidth scaleFactor)))
                        ((set! imageFactor (/ imageHeight scaleFactor)))
                    )
                    (set! imageWidth (/ imageWidth imageFactor))
                    (set! imageHeight (/ imageHeight imageFactor))
                )
                (gimp-image-scale-full image imageWidth imageHeight INTERPOLATION-CUBIC)
                (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable filename filename)
                (gimp-image-delete image)
            )
            (set! filelist (cdr filelist))
        )
    )
)
```